# Properties file no longer found/invalid block type

Tags: java, maven, jbpm

The following code was working (correctly) to read a property file in the jar under src/main/resources in my Eclipse project:

```
  public static void getClassPathProperties() {
      
      LOGGER.debug("getClassPathProperties Enter");
      try (final InputStream input = Utils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("environment.properties")) {
          properties.load(input);

      } catch (Exception e) {
              LOGGER.error("Unable to find environment.properties on classpath to Utils.class");
              e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
```

This code was part of a JBPM WorkItemHandler to enable specific containers (jar files) to use environment-specific properties.  As a jar of WorkItemHandler's, this jar is a dependency of another jar that is the container called by JBPM.  I added a line that adds an extra property to the connection of a REST call from JBPM to an external service:

```
    connection.setRequestProperty("EDIPI_NUM", edipi);
    connection.setRequestProperty("NPKE_SUBJECT", npkeSubject);
    connection.setRequestProperty("NPKE_UPN", npkeSubject);  // Line added
```

did a clean rebuild and now get the error:

```
^[[0m^[[31m16:07:56,247 ERROR [com.goprecise.ams.handlers.utils.Utils] (default task-1000) Unable to find environment.properties on classpath to Utils.class
^[[0m^[[31m16:07:56,247 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1000) java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid block type
^[[0m^[[31m16:07:56,247 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1000)      at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
^[[0m^[[31m16:07:56,247 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1000)      at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
^[[0m^[[31m16:07:56,247 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1000)      at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
^[[0m^[[31m16:07:56,247 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1000)      at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:435)
^[[0m^[[31m16:07:56,247 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1000)      at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)
^[[0m^[[31m16:07:56,247 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1000)      at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
^[[0m^[[31m16:07:56,247 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1000)      at com.goprecise.ams.handlers.utils.Utils.getClassPathProperties(Utils.java:55)
```

The environment.properties file is placed at the root directory in the built jar.  Because I have a complex pom.xml, I wonder if something in the pom.xml could be causing the code to no longer work?  If not, what else could be causing the error?

```
 <build>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/java</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <includes>
          <include>*.*</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>${project.build.directory}/maven-shared-archive-resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
          <include>*.part</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>templating-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>filter-src</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>filter-sources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-repository-resources</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
              <resources>
                <resource>
                  <directory>target/generated-sources/annotations</directory>
                  <includes>
                    <include>repoindex.html</include>
                    <include>*.wid</include>
                  </includes>
                  <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
              </resources>
              <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
          <annotationProcessors>
            <annotationProcessor>org.jbpm.process.workitem.core.util.WidProcessor</annotationProcessor>
          </annotationProcessors>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-AwidName=${project.artifactId}</arg>
            <arg>-AgenerateTemplates=true</arg>
            <arg>-AgenerateWids=true</arg>
            <arg>-AwidsResources=${project.artifactId}.wid:widtemplate.st</arg>
            <arg>-AtemplateResources=kie-deployment-descriptor.xml:kie-ddtemplate.st,serviceinfo.json:serviceinfo.st,repoindex.html:repoindex.part,index.html:indextemplate.st,${project.artifactId}.bpmn2:defaultprocess.st</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <!-- root module has no assembly so ignore it -->
          <ignoreMissingDescriptor>true</ignoreMissingDescriptor>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>${project.basedir}/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
          <archive>
            <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>integration-test-execution</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <builddir>${project.build.directory}</builddir>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
          <failIfNoTests>false</failIfNoTests>
          <test>${it.test}</test>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*IntegrationTest.java</include>
          </includes>
          <argLine>${failsafe.arg.line}</argLine>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.commonjava.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-sources-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>project-sources</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>archive</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*Test.java</include>
          </includes>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest.java</exclude>
          </excludes>
          <argLine>-Xmx1024m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <apple.awt.UIElement>true</apple.awt.UIElement>
            <org.uberfire.nio.git.daemon.enabled>false</org.uberfire.nio.git.daemon.enabled>
            <org.uberfire.nio.git.ssh.enabled>false</org.uberfire.nio.git.ssh.enabled>
            <org.uberfire.sys.repo.monitor.disabled>true</org.uberfire.sys.repo.monitor.disabled>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
          </execution>
          <!-- No OSGi manifestEntries for <goal>jar</goal>: if it supported, then felix has already added them -->
          <execution>
            <id>test-jar</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <skipIfEmpty>true</skipIfEmpty>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>**/logback-test.xml</exclude>
                <exclude>**/jndi.properties</exclude>
              </excludes>
              <archive>
                <manifestEntries>
                  <Bundle-SymbolicName>${java.module.name}.tests</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                  <Bundle-Version>
                    ${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.${parsedVersion.incrementalVersion}.${osgi.snapshot.qualifier}
                  </Bundle-Version>
                  <Bundle-Name>${project.name}</Bundle-Name>
                  <Bundle-Vendor>${project.organization.name}</Bundle-Vendor>
                </manifestEntries>
              </archive>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
              <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <resourceBundles>
            <resourceBundle>org.jbpm.contrib:template-resources:${version.org.kie}</resourceBundle>
          </resourceBundles>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: Is this related to [your Q a week ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68777249/1744774) and did my answer there not help you?

Comment: Indeed it is!  I just accepted one of your answers that I found independently by pouring over the pom.xml.  I got it to work, except that the missing header would not let a downstream service be authenticated in some instances.  Adding the header to the Java, rebuilding, and I started to get the error "Unable to find environment.properties on classpath to Utils.class ... java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid block type".  Since the file is in the root directory of the jar, I wonder if the jar can no longer be decompressed